# Php form: email copy to sender

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a simple form. Basically trying to replicate share by email thought this would be sufficient. I'd like to send a copy of this email to the $email variable (Yeah that stripslashes might not be necessary), any ideas on how to do so? Came across bunch of posts through google but couldn't figure it out;

```
<?php
        $EmailFrom = "admin@test.com";
        $EmailTo  = "admin@test.com";
        $Subject = "Check out this video.";
        $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])) : false; 

        $Body = "Take a look at this; youtubelink...";

        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
        header('Location: /#');
?>
```

Comment: Perform `email()` function with another set of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit your script like this, the copy will be sent only if the original will:

```
<?php
    $EmailFrom = "admin@test.com";
    $EmailTo  = "admin@test.com";
    $Subject = "Check out this video.";
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])) : false; 

    $Body = "Take a look at this; youtubelink...";

    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

    if ($success)
        mail($EmailFrom, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

    header('Location: /#');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another mail(); function

```
<?php
        $EmailFrom = "admin@test.com";
        $EmailTo  = "admin@test.com";
        $Subject = "Check out this video.";
        $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])) : false; 

        $BodyReceiver = "Take a look at this; youtubelink...";
        $BodySender = "You sent the following message " . $BodyReceiver . " to " . $EmailTo . ".";

        $successReceiver = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $BodyReceiver, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
        $successSender = mail($EmailFrom, $Subject, $BodySender, "From: <no-reply@text.com");
        header('Location: /#');
?>
```

or something like that...

As bozdoz suggested you might do it with Bcc, but then it will be a total copy of the original. You will not be able to change the sender email or the massage (for instance to "You sent the following massage ... to ..." and whatnot.